# using new-psdrive name as source variable for msdeploy source parameter does not work

Tags: powershell, msdeploy, webdeploy

// Create a new powershell drive

```
$psw = ConvertTo-SecureString %deployment.password% -AsPlainText -force
$cred = new-object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "MyUser, $psw
New-PSDrive -Credential $cred -Name ImportFolder -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\MyShare\Exchange\MyFolder
```

// Create a full source path

```
$sourcePath = ImportFolder:\$versionPath\audio
```

// Deploy with msdeploy and the $sourcePath

```
$path = "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe";
$verb = "-verb:sync";
$src = "-source:contentPath=`"$sourcePath`"";
$dest = "-dest:contentPath=%TargetIISPath%,wmsvc='%Computername%:%deployment.iis.port%/msdeploy.axd',username=%system.Username%,password=%system.Password%";
Invoke-Expression "&'$path' --% $verb $src $dest -verbose -allowUntrusted";

Remove-PSDrive ImportFolder
```

I get the error:

```
The term 'ImportFolder:\$versionPath\audio' is not recognized as the name of a 
[21:07:32][Step 6/7] cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
[21:07:32][Step 6/7] name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
[21:07:32][Step 6/7] again.At
```

The problem is that msdeploy assumes the sourcePath ImportFolder is literally named "ImportFolder" but actually it is a powershell drive with a mapped path...

How can I fix that?

I do NOT want to use "net use X:\ path" because its buggy in my environment.

Comment: You'll want to enclose that `$sourcePath` value in quotes: `$sourcePath = "ImportFolder:\$versionPath\audio"`. That being said, `msdeploy.exe` won't be able to resolve the psdrive (since `msdeploy.exe` is not PowerShell)

Comment: I did as you said but it did not help now I get another error which I understand...: Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
 More Information: Site 'ImportFolder:' does not exist. It takes it literally...

Comment: That's literally what I told you - it won't work even though you fix the `$sourcePath` string. `msdeploy` **IS NOT POWERSHELL**.

Comment: Then I misunderstood you. I thought you gave me the hint to doublequote the sourcePath...

Comment: @Elisabeth you can accomplish what you want without even touching PSDrives. Just use the UNC path of the destination folder like you did with creating the PSDrive. PSDrives are only available in the host you create them in, so it won't be available to the msdeploy executable. If you need to be able to do things on remote drives without needing to elevate your current interactive user token (logged in) you can hack registry to allow an elevated token to do so.

Comment: I just made it work with net use again. Somehow the syntax changed from a windows 7 machine to a new windows server 2012... thats odd.

Comment: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{CDCBCFCA-3CDC-436f-A4E2-0E02075250C2}
Deleting the 'RunAs' key will allow you to browse remote drives while on an unelevated non-privileged account by running certain programs with a privileged or elevated token/account. You can access remote drives with "\\fqdn-or-cname\c$\pathtosubdirectory" or any drive letter locally mapped instead of c$.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. Do you know wether it should work with webdeploy then?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit old, but you can just use a Name with a letter for your PSDrive, and then you can use that drive letter with msdeploy

```
New-PSDrive -Credential $cred -Name "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\MyShare\Exchange\MyFolder

$sourcePath = "X:\$versionPath\audio"
```